# Assert count in nested json

Tags: groovy, assert, assertion, katalon-studio

I have following Katalon code to make sure the count response from API is correct
but I am getting an error so I need help to see what is missing in my code.

```
No signature of method: Script1568233794882.assertThat() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [29]
```

```html
response text: 
{
    "Error": {
        "A": {
            "dependency": [
                
            ],
            "duplicateRows": [
                
            ],
            "requiredFieldRows": [
                
            ]
        }
    },
    "Good": {
        "A": {
            "count": 29
        },
        "B": {
            "count": 35
        },
        "C": {
            "count": 37
        }
    },
    "type": "Test"
}
```

I have tried this

```html
def response = WS.sendRequest(requestObject)
def responseList = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response.getResponseText())
println('response text: \n' + JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(responseList)))
assertThat(responseList.Good.A.count).isEqualTo("29")
```

Also tried using [0], but it is also not working with error `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer`

```
assertThat(responseList.Good[0].A).isEqualTo("29")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the plain Groovy assert. Change your assertion line to the following:

```
assert responseList.Good.A.count == 29
```